# Modify data representation in Sphinx

Tags: python, python-sphinx

I have the following module:

```
"""
This is a test.
"""

class Test(dict):
    """ Should always appear empty in the docs. """
    def __repr__(self): return '{}'
    def __str__(self): return '{}'
    def __format__(self, *args): return '{}'

#: This is a dictionary that appears appears to be empty in the docs, but isn't
#: really. Enjoy!
test = Test()
test['a'] = 1
test['b'] = 2
```

I document the module with

```
.. automodule:: test
   :members:
```

Everything compiles just fine. However, when I look at the documentation of `test.test`, I see

> `test.test = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}`

How does sphinx autodoc get the representation of the data object, and how can I override it? The whole point of the `Test` class is to make the following output:

> `test.test = {}`

Comment: If you want to see `test.test = {}` in the output, then you'll have to remove `test['a'] = 1` and `test['b'] = 2`. But why do you want to document a specific instance of a class in the first place?

Comment: @mzjn. In my actual code, I have a registry of stuff. It's an instance of a class that's not part of the public API, but the registry itself is very much a part of the API. My question is more about how Sphinx gets the representation of the object than anything. I assumed initially that it was through `__repr__`, but that's clearly not the case.

Comment: If be happy to accept your statement that Sphinx will never print `{}` for me, but I'd have to see a pretty convincing explanation as to why. The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is that it implements a custom representation for specific types like dict and tuple, but I find that very hard to believe.

Comment: During the documentation build, Sphinx imports the module and a `test.test` instance is created and populated. `test.test = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}` is the representation of that. Only an empty dictionary would result in  `test.test = {}`.

Comment: @mzjn. I think we're at cross purposes here. I fully understand that the mapping is being populated. However, it's not a regular dict. I've made it so that repr(test) == format(test) == str(test) == '{}'. Where does the string in the documentation come from then?

Comment: I think I found it. The string representation is created by the `object_description` function. https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/util/inspect.py#L238.

Comment: @mzjn. I appreciate that mightily. Looks like all I have to do is make my object unsortable to make it default to repr.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dictionary value is created in the `object_description` function in this Python file: https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/util/inspect.py. The function provides "a repr() implementation that returns text safe to use in reST context".

The representation created by Sphinx can be overridden by using the [`autodata`](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/autodoc.html#directive-autodata) directive with the `annotation` option.

```
.. automodule:: test
   :members:
   :exclude-members: test

.. autodata:: test.test
   :annotation: = {}
```

Comment: I posted my initial attempt as a separate answer because it is so silly. This is actually a very elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@mzjn's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51487209/modify-data-representation-in-sphinx/51502978#comment89953848_51487209), I came up with an incredibly hacky solution that actually works in my very specific case, but I would not recommend to anyone else.

The trick is in the following lines in the [`object_description`](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/3e57ea0a5253ac198c1bff16c40abe71951bb586/sphinx/util/inspect.py#L238) function:

> ```
> if isinstance(object, dict):
>     try:
>         sorted_keys = sorted(object)
>     except Exception:
>         pass # Cannot sort dict keys, fall back to generic repr
>     ...
> ```

If `sorted` fails, the description defaults over to `repr`. The easiest way to make `sorted` fail is to make my class `Test` non-iterable:

```
def __iter__(self):
    raise TypeError('no!')
```

While this is extremely non-recommended for general purpose dictionary extensions, it works fine for my `Test` class, and produces the expected result.

Comment: Hacky but interesting!